# MonoTouch and Storyboards: how to come from table cell to details view

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard, tableview

I'm creating a MonoTouch application and have a UITableViewController from where I tried to create a segue from a cell to a detailed view. 
There is no problem in creating the segue but when i click a cell nothing happens.

I was hoping that this could be done with no lines of code but it doesn't seem like it.

Any ideas?

Thx
/Nicolaj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "no problem creating the segue" do you mean using interface builder?  You will still need to handle the event in code.  I'm not aware of any automatic handling of the row-selection event.

I see another thread that may help you: [How to reference tableView from a view controller during a segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931116/how-to-reference-tableview-from-a-view-controller-during-a-segue)

Monotouch has a tableview [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/WorldCities/WorldCities/WorldCitiesListController.cs) showing the usage of **prepareForSegue** and **RowSelected**

Comment: thx a lot. i'm pretty sure the WorldCities sample will do the trick for me