# How to access TableView from selector method of toolbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, selector

I hope someone out there can help me understand where I'm going wrong here

I've got a TableViewController, and in order save the contents of the tableview, I've changed the -(void)viewDidLoad code to add a Save button ...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                           initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave 
                                           target:self 
                                           action:@selector(insertCustomData)
                                           ];
```

However, within my `insertCustomData` function, I need to access the tableview as I would elsewhere within the controller code.  I need to access my tableview in order to validate the cell values prior to saving to the database.  I can see how to pass the reference to the tableview from the toolbar definition (if that's how it should be done)

I'm not even sure if I should be accessing the values of the tableview cells at this stage (I am attempting to build an NSObject of the cell data to pass over to a validation function in the data controller I've written, to validate and save into a SQLite database)

Sorry if this seems trivial, but right now I'm stuck on this, and any help would be appreciated

Thanks

[Update]

I am using the tableView for a data entry screen, so initially there is no data to display.  The tableView is within the bounds of the tableview controller, but due to the way I need to do it, I am creating the cells at runtime using a custom cell definition (in a .xib file, with associated .h and .m files).  The custom cell definition is simply one UILabel and one UITextField (that is used for the data entry)

The fields have placeholder to indicate what needs to be entered but are otherwise empty.  I did deliberate whether I still needed to base the tableView on an array or dictionary object for capturing the user input

The class I am writing this in has the definition `@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`, as this was created from the UITableViewController initial template (or whatever its called)

I get the feeling I should capture the data earlier and only call the save method from the selector ?

Do I just need to create an NSArray with nil NSStrings and assign this to each UITextField/Cell in the tableView ?  If I do, will the text entry go into this NSArray ?

**[SOLVED - Answer below]**

What I needed was to modify the standard .h file to this

```
@interface CustomViewController : UITableViewController  <UITextFieldDelegate> {
  IBOutlet UITableView *MyTableView;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *MyTableView;
```

Then in interface builder I was able to ctrl-link the tableview to my new declaration.  THIS was the most important step, as this then ensures that rather than a generic tableView , I was able to modify the main code that builds the cells dynamically to reference this, as below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EditableCustomCell";
  EditableCustomCell *cell = [[self MyTableView] dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

I also added a `synthesize MyTableView` at the top

This made `MyTableView` accessible to any new method I needed to write, making accessing it from the leftBarButtonItem selector `insertCustomData` a breeze

Many thanks to **Kimpoy** for the help in this !

(Note: Ironically after completing this, looking at a previous question I posted, I should have learnt from my previous issues with segues and tableviews [How to reference tableView from a view controller during a segue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7931116/1018394))

Comment: jeeeezzz...thanks for the special mention, man! Didn't expect that. I was just trying to help out. hehe... It made my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the AddViewController.h file:

```
@interface AddViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UITableView             *tableViewInfo;
    UITextField             *txtFieldUsed;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewInfo;
@end
```

In the AddViewController.m file:

```
@implementation AddViewController

@synthesize tableViewInfo; // Synthesize your tableViewInfo property

// Called to get the text values from the textfields in the table view cells/rows
- (NSDictionary *)getValueForTextField:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSMutableDictionary *mutDictCredential = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
        NSIndexPath *idxCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:idxCell];
        for (UITextField *textField in cell.contentView.subviews) {
            if ([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && row == textField.tag) {
                NSString *strText = textField.text;
                if (!strText) {
                strText = @"";
                }
                if (row == 0) {
                [mutDictCredential setObject:strText forKey:@"CoffeeName"];
                }
                else if (row == 1) {
                [mutDictCredential setObject:strText forKey:@"Price"];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return mutDictCredential;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Tableview datasource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[self tableViewInfo] dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        CGRect rect = [cell frame];
        // Create editable textfield within cell or row
        UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + 10, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width - 40, rect.size.height)];
        [txtField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
        [txtField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
        [txtField setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [txtField setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
        [txtField setTag:indexPath.row];
        [txtField setDelegate:self];

        // Set cells texts
        switch ([txtField tag]) {
          case 0:
            [txtField setPlaceholder:@"Coffee Name"];
            [txtField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
            [txtField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyNext];
            break;
          case 1:
            [txtField setPlaceholder:@"Price"];
            [txtField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:txtField];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        [txtField release];
     }
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Tableview delegate

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20.0;
}

// This can be your insertCustomData
- (void) save_Clicked:(id)sender {
    // Get data from table
    [self getValueForTextField:[self tableViewInfo]];

    NSMutableDictionary *tempMutDictInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[self getValueForTextField:[self tableViewInfo]]];

    NSString *paramName = [tempMutDictInfo valueForKey:@"CoffeeName"];
    NSString *paramMessage = [tempMutDictInfo valueForKey:@"Price"];
    [tempMutDictInfo release];

    NSMutableDictionary *mutDictInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [mutDictInfo setObject:paramName == nil ? @"" : paramName forKey:@"CoffeeName"];
    [mutDictInfo setObject:paramMessage == nil ? @"" : paramMessage forKey:@"Price"];

    // Database
    SQLAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SQLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //Create a Coffee Object.
    Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:0];
    coffeeObj.coffeeName = [mutDictInfo valueForKey:@"CoffeeName"];
    NSDecimalNumber *temp = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:[mutDictInfo valueForKey:@"Price"]];

    [mutDictInfo release];

    coffeeObj.price = temp;
    [temp release];
    coffeeObj.isDirty = NO;
    coffeeObj.isDetailViewHydrated = YES;

    //Add the object
    [appDelegate addCoffee:coffeeObj];

    //Dismiss the controller.
    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [tableViewInfo release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

You can use this as a reference.

Comment: Thanks Kimpoy, I've update the original text with an update to your question.  Hope you can help

Comment: Just let me know if you encountered any problem. Good luck!

Comment: FANTASTIC !!!  Many thanks Kimpoy.  I was most of the way there, but that code really helped me iron out the issues.  I will update my question with a more detailed answer for completness

Answer (score 0):

I would assign 2 additional properties to my view controller. 1 for my tableview and 1 for my datasource.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure to what you are referring, can you be a little more specific ?