# How to fix "nib but didn't get a UITableView" error?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uiview

Why I get this error?

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController
>   loadView] loaded the "pB1-re-lu8-view-o7U-YG-E7m" nib but didn't get a
>   UITableView.'

here is my code:

```
class FriendListTableViewController: UITableViewController{


var objects = NSMutableArray()
var dataArray = [["firstName":"Debasis","lastName":"Das"],["firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"],["firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Doe"],["firstName":"Mary","lastName":"Jane"]]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table View

 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataArray.count
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let object = dataArray[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(10) as! UILabel).text = object["firstName"] as? String
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(11) as! UILabel).text = object["lastName"] as? String
    return cell
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return false
}
```

my storyboard is like this:

[image: storyboard]

Comment: how can i do that properly?

Comment: Write in Void Did Load Method..   self.delegate=self;   self.dataSource=self;   and in ViewController.h Extend.. <UITableViewDelegate ,UITableViewDataSource>

Comment: Try this and inform me after solving your problem.

Comment: @ EgaSetyaPutra tell me what error you got.

Comment: isn't your answer written in objective-c? cause I'm using swift

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have face same issue once upon time, and So stupid mistake it was, I have subclass the `UITableViewController`, where I have added `UITableView` in `UIViewController`

From your storyboard Image, it may be solved if you use `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`, Just try that way can solve your issue,like

```
class FriendListTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
```

Comment: I think your answer is how we set delegate using objective-c, I already set the delegate like this "FriendListTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource". But I still have the same error

Comment: Have you checked that your `UITableView` has attached with top-level. You can check it by `UIStoryBoard`'s view hierarchy.

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra the above answer is using swift.. you are using swift or objective c?

Comment: @ViralSavaj have you read the comment of Ega Setya Putra on your answer. if not read first then read it first and then tell me...

Comment: @AshokLondhe, I have updated answer just after comment, so please take note of that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76888/discussion-between-viral-savaj-and-ashok-londhe).

Comment: I'm using swift , @ViralSavaj thanks for your answer ,it solved my problem

Comment: What do I do if my UITableView has not appeared in the top-level in the storyboard's view hierarchy? It stills shows that it's a viewController. @ViralSavaj

Comment: I also can't access the tableView delegate through `self`. `self.tableView.reloadData()` doesn't work with the solution you posted.

Answer (score 4):

**SWIFT 2 UPDATE**

I tried @Viralsavaj's answer but it didn't work for me until I "hooked up" the tableView as an outlet from the storyboard in the ViewController.

like this: `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!`

Also add this to your class as @Viralsavaj mentioned:

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
```

I used specifically this link help as well: [How to reference tableView from a view controller during a segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931116/how-to-reference-tableview-from-a-view-controller-during-a-segue)

Just drag your tableView into the ViewController and make it an outlet. Then you can reference its properties such as `self.tableView.reloadData()`.

This property as well as others that referenced the `tableView` were giving me errors until I added the tableView as a referencing outlet.

Hope this helps those in the future.

Comment: yep , I often using the same method as yours. It's easier

Comment: @lukeslvi: From your comment on my answer and with this answer, I couldn't identify whether your problem solved, or still exist?

Comment: Doesn't exist anymore. Thanks a lot. I combined your suggestions with a suggestion from another link. And now it works.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue with Swift 2, Xcode 7.2, I changed a `View Controller` I dragged to my `Storyboard` to a custom `UITableViewController` class, I then dragged a `Table View` onto the `View Controller`. I didn't realize I placed it as a child of the `View` that was part of the original `View Controller` I dragged onto the `Storyboard`.

I simply deleted the `View` and added the Table View again as the first child of the Super View.