# UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC" nib but didn't get a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

How to Solve this crash in Xcode. in UITableView

UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC" nib but didn't get a UITableView.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028129/how-to-fix-nib-but-didnt-get-a-uitableview-error/30028210#30028210

Comment: This may be the scenario you are facing, Link Code is in Swift, you you need answer in Objective-c then plz ask,

Comment: yes,i want ans for objective-C

Comment: Try this `@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>` at you view controller header.

Comment: Is the viewcontroller in your nib a `UITableViewController`? How exactly do you load the nib? There is an unmatched bracket in your title. Please edot your question to clarify

Comment: I am working similar to this demo http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/itunes-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

Comment: Using Storyboard? If yes, then check whether you have taken direct `UITableViewController` or `UITableView` In `UIViewController`?

Comment: Using xib, Yes i have took [UITableViewController] direct as per demo.

Comment: Will you plz post some top lines of code of the controller on which you are getting error?

Comment: NSURL *url = (NSURL *)[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
        if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
            [viewController handleOpenURL:url];
        }
        return YES;

My app getting Crash on this code  in `Appdelegate.m`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a `UITableViewController`, the view property in the storyboard must be connected to a `UITableView` object.  Either you don't have the view property connected or you have it connected to the wrong type of view.