# Swift tableView ambigious

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem with a `UITableView` populated via a remote `JSON` file. I've got the two functions:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return newsdata.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)  as! NewsTableViewCell
    let nachricht = newsdata[indexPath.row]
    cell.NewsHeadline.text = nachricht.newstitel
    return cell
}
```

set up and running, and segue with the ID "ShowNewsDetail" connected to another view controller with a `UIWebView`. However, connecting the two controllers in code doesn't work:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
        sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "ShowNewsDetails" {
            let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController
                as! NewsDetailViewController
            let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
            let row = myIndexPath?.row
            detailViewController.webSite = newsdata[row!]
        }
}
```

Xcode 7.1 reports "Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView'" and points to the two functions before it as "candidates". I have no idea how to pick a candidate or fix this annoying error.

Comment: what are the two functions before the error that Xcode is pointing to?  the `numberOfRowsInSection`" & "`cellForRowAtIndexPath`" functions?

Comment: what class did you initialize? Is it a VIewController or tableView controller? refer to this link if so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028129/how-to-fix-nib-but-didnt-get-a-uitableview-error/33484728?noredirect=1#comment54770542_33484728 . I'm guessing you didn't initialize the tableView.

Comment: lukeslvi answer led me to the error. While the app did fill the table, the outlet from the Table View to the controller was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and all works fine. But in my case Swift applied some changes. My xCode is 7.1 version also. I just pass a string in a detail controller.

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "ShowNewsDetails" {
            let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController
            as! NewsDetailViewController
            let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            let index = myIndexPath.row
            detailViewController.tempStr = String(index)
        }
    }
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have an outlet that is also named tableView. The compiler sees the symbol for the outlet as being the same as the symbols for the two method names.

So instead of this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

rename your outlet to something else:

```
@IBOutlet weak var newsTableView: UITableView!
```

Then use this outlet variable in your `prepareForSegue` code:

```
let myIndexPath = self.newsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers - I would upvote them if I could. lukeslvi led me to the answer - table view wasn't initialized properly.